# Configure js-beautify within a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, js-beautify

I am using [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) (the html-beautify option) to format html that is being displayed on my page, <s>it displays but it's collapsing all the html to 1 line which is obviously not ideal because it's a pain to read.</s> It is basically trying to format HTML as Javascript because the actual `html beautify` is not being applied.

I'm using it in react as below inside a specific component file for that item does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import htmlBeautify from 'js-beautify'

const htmlString = htmlBeautify(renderToStaticMarkup(<Component />))

export default () =>
    <Example staticMarkup={htmlString}>
      <Component />
    </Example>
```

**Update:**
`<Example/>` is another component that renders out a bunch of additional stuff like a markdown description.

I'm using https://github.com/alexlande/react-style-guide to create a styleguide and passing the static html markup to `staticMarkup` prop to display rather than just showing the react component which in this context isn't particulary useful.

Comment: What does `<Example>` do with `staticMarkup` ?

Comment: Example is just another component that renders out a bunch of additional stuff like a markdown description. 

I'm using https://github.com/alexlande/react-style-guide to create a styleguide and passing the static markup to "staticMarkup" prop to display rather than just showing the react component which in this context isn't particulary useful. Will update my question with the extra info.